# How to use chunk with AngularJS in blade laravel?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use chunk with AngularJS and laravel blade. to split loop with two column. How can I use it with AngularJS?

I  try this code:

```
<tr dir-paginate="employee in allstfs|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:itemsPerPage" current-page="currentPage" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc">
    <td>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="7" class="imgtd">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="{{URL::to('src/img/staff_images')}}/@{{employee.picture}}">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="titletd">@{{employee.fName}} @{{employee.lName}} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@{{employee.fName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@{{employee.lName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@{{employee.sex}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@{{employee.dob}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@{{employee.position}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
```

I want to use chunk to loop with two column like this code in blade laravel:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="15px">
    @foreach($para->chunk(2) as $chunk)
    <tr style="border-bottom: solid #EEEEEE 1px;">
        @foreach($chunk as $value) ------ @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach

</table>
```

How can I use chunk with AngularJS?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: In laravel we can use @foreach loop with chunk(para) how can we use it in angular??

Comment: @Jerodev You see my second code?? i want to get result like this with angluar how can i?